# How can I assign Cell Part as Variable?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to set a number in a cell to be a variable yet still keep text in it. That way it can be added up later using that variable.

I want it to say something like

> Justicar Aatrox: 975

And have 975 be the Value of that Cell to be added up later... I've been searching and trying to figure this out for like 2 hours now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of different possible approaches and answers.  What is best depends on how you want to use the contents.

1. "Justicar Aatrox" is just a label and the only use for it is as identifying information displayed in that cell.  @Hannu's answer is perfect for that.
2. "Justicar Aatrox" is just a comment to help you keep track of things on the spreadsheet and you don't even need it displayed unless you look at the cell contents.  You could use a trick like this to store the text string:

   =N("Justicar Aatrox:")+975

   It will be visible if you look inside the cell, but the N() function converts the label to a value of zero so the 975 can be used as a numerical value with just a reference to the cell.
3. "Justicar Aatrox" has value as data.  You might want to filter the data based on that value, sort the data based on it, search for the cell based on the value, use the value as a target for a lookup function to find data in other columns associated with it, use it as a condition for summing up values, do conditional formatting based on it, etc.  In that case, the information can't be used if it is contained inside a "comment" or exists only as formatting.

   It would need to be normal cell content.  The efficient way to do it in that case is with two cells, a text cell for the label and an adjacent numeric cell for the value. Each can then be used directly with a simple cell reference.
4. If you need to keep them together in one cell for some reason, that would complicate using either the label (for purposes as described above),or the value.  To use the value, you would need to extract the number every time you want to use it.  Rather than a simple cell reference for the value, you would need a formula that finds the value in the string; something like searching for the colon and then using its position in the string to calculate where the number starts, extracting the number, and then converting it from text to a numerical value.  The simple "A1" reference would become a long, convoluted formula every place the number is needed, like:

   VALUE(MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)+2,LEN(A1)-FIND(":",A1)-1))

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but here is an answer to what I THINK you're asking.

Type your number in any cell, then re-select the cell and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>.
A dialog opens.
In the left side of it you see a number of words for data formatting types.
Some are valid for numbers, others require data of other types.

Find the word "Custom" and select it, it is usually the last item - it might be you need scroll down in the list.
Now you have a list of items on the right side too, above these is a field where you can fill in a "format code" (look it up in the help!).
For an example `"Justicar Aatrox: "0` will display your cell content as `Justicar Aatrox: 975` - your 975 is the number in the cell.
Try it out.

The cell CONTAINS the number, the above defines how it should be SHOWN.

Comment: It's bad practice to combine a text label and numeric value in one cell, and it complicates maintaining the data.  However, if you need to do it for some reason, this is a clever way. +1

Comment: I don't necessarily think it is bad practice to do something like this.  It does make it harder to maintain for less experienced people.  Someone who knows about this can easily figure that out.  I only wish the custom format can accept a formula to make it more versatile

Comment: @fixer1234 - the only "mix" is how it is displayed. Comparable to printf() formatting codes in C.